# org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException using ObjectMapper

Tags: java, jackson

I am trying to make a call to my REST Service using Object Mapper.

```
url = new URL("http://phx5qa01c-8539.host.com:8080/bservice/BService/v1/getSimpleString");

String str = mapper.readValue(url, String.class);
```

And that url will give me this String back-

> { attributes : [ { nm : "SELLERS2" vt : "java.util.Map" status :
>   "SUCCESS" jsonValue :
>   "{"lv":[{"v":{"regSiteId":null,"userState":null,"userId":609},"cn":1}],"lmd":20130206211109}"
>   } ]}

When I am trying that URL on the browser, I am getting back the above String. But as soon as I do the same thing in the code. I am getting this Exception below-

> org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize
>   instance of java.lang.String out of START_OBJECT token

Can anyone help me with this why I am getting this exception below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jackson is trying to deserialize your json as a new string object but the properties dont match up e.g. it cant find a method String.setAttributes(). The 'out of START_OBJECT token' is a catch-all for any deserialisation errors, there may be more info further down the stack trace.

Try:

```
Map myMap = mapper.readValue(url, Map.class);
```

Or if you really want the string, don't use Jackson just read the url to a string using standard java code or [commons-io](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-2.4/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.html#toString%28java.net.URL%29):

```
String str = IOUtils.toString(url);
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. When I am trying your first approach, I am getting this exception back-  `java.io.EOFException: No content to map to Object due to end of input`? Any thoughts why it is happening?